# Is this true (Trigonometry) and if so, can it be proved by induction?

Tags: trigonometry, induction

I'm considering functions of the form $\cos{(n\theta)}+\sin{(n\theta)}$ and have noticed that when $n=4k+1$ for positive integers $k$ the expression seems to be divisible by $\cos{\theta}+\sin{\theta}$ (also works in the trivial case when $k=0$) and when $n=4k-1$ the expression is divisible by $\cos{\theta}-\sin{\theta}$

I've tested this idea for a few integers $k$ and it seems to work, so I'm wondering if it can be proven. Induction seems like the logical choice but exactly how to proceed is, for now, beyond my grasp.

Does anyone have any ideas?
(or a counter-example?)

Comment: Does "divisible" here mean the quotient is an integer?

Comment: If you want to try induction you can try expanding $\cos([4(k+1)+1]\theta) = \cos((4k+1)\theta + 4\theta) = \cos((4k+1) \theta)\cos(4\theta) -\sin((4k+1) \theta)\sin (4\theta)$ and $\sin([4(k+1)+1]\theta)=\sin((4k+1)\theta + 4\theta) = \sin((4k+1)\theta\cos(4\theta) + \cos((4k+1)\theta)\sin (4\theta)$. Does that work?

Comment: Actually,   If you state you proposition as $\cos((4k\pm 1)\theta) + \sin((4k\pm 1)\theta)$ is divisible by $\cos \theta \pm \sin \theta$ then doing induction by expanding $\cos([4(k\pm 1)\theta + 2\theta)$ will do it in my comment above.

Comment: @peterwhy - I mean that $\cos{\theta}+\sin{\theta}$ is a factor. I'm not sure "integer" has a proper meaning in this instance.

Comment: @fleablood - that is basically what I started doing. It certainly worked for SPECIFIC values of $k$, but I'm not yet seeing how it works for ALL.

Comment: @fleablood For what it's worth, depending on the browser magnification, your first posted comment is hard to read.  MathSE comments do not always format *run-on* math expressions well.  True that avoiding such run-ons does makes it difficult for you to express the math ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon=\pm1$. First note that $\cos t+\varepsilon\sin t=\sqrt2\cos(t-\varepsilon\pi/4)$, so that your question amounts to

> Prove that $\cos(\theta-\varepsilon\pi/4)$ divides $\cos((4k+1)\theta-\varepsilon\pi/4)$.

Moreover, letting $x:=\theta-\varepsilon\pi/4$, we have $\cos((4k+1)x)=\cos((4k+1)\theta-\varepsilon k\pi-\varepsilon\pi/4)=(-1)^k\cos((4k+1)\theta-\varepsilon\pi/4)$, so the task simplifies to:

> Prove that $\cos x$ divides $\cos((4k+1)x)$.

Actually, we even have
$$\forall n\text{ odd},\quad\cos x\mid\cos(nx)=T_n(\cos x)\quad\text{in}\quad\Bbb Z[\cos x]$$
since the $n$th [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $T_n(X)\in\Bbb Z[X]$ [has the parity of $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Symmetry) (there are many ways to prove it, including [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Recurrence_definition)).

Edit: alternatively,

- either notice directly (using [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula#Formulae_for_cosine_and_sine_individually) and the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)) that
  $$\begin{align}\cos((2m+1)x)&=\operatorname{Re}\left((\cos x+i\sin x)^{2m+1}\right)\\&=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{2m+1}{2j}(-1)^j\sin^{2j}x\cos^{2m+1-2j}x\\
  &=\cos x\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{2m+1}{2j}(\cos^2x-1)^j\cos^{2m+1-2j}x
  \end{align}$$
- or use induction:
  [$$\cos((2m+1)x)=2\cos x\cos(2mx)-\cos((2m-1)x).$$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sum-to-product_identities)

Comment: Thanks - a good answer, but a bit more complicated than what I was hoping for. I have a very limited understanding of Chebyshev polynomials (I do not doubt their usefulness, it is just a more difficult idea than I think/hope the problem requires).   I was hoping/thinking that a more fundamental induction proof was possible, along the lines suggested by @fleablood.

Comment: Ah... thanks @Anne... that $\cos{((2m+1)x)$ expansion is a stroke of genius! Brilliant.